# Template not showing data (is blank) fetched from sqlite using view function by passing a parameter

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sqlite

I have implemented a feature where there is a "view" button next to each row fetched from the DB. When clicked it is sending the `id` of the event to view URL. The view then fetches the filtered data from SQLite; but it is not showing the data in the template.

**template.html**

```
<td><a href="{% url 'event' eid=ev.id %}">View</a></td>
```

**urls.py**

```
path('<int:eid>', views.event_det, name='event'),
```

**views.py**

```
def event_det(request, eid):
    data = Event.objects.filter(id=eid)
    return render(request, 'event_details.html', {'event': data})
```

**template.html** to show the fetched output

```
{% for ev in event %}
        <div class="card mb-12">
            <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img src="{% static 'face_detector/datasets/9187/color-1.png' %}" class="card-img" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h2 class="card-title">{{ ev.name }}</h2>
                        <p class="card-text">{{ ev.description }}</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
...
```

Comment: are you sure your objects filter is returning any data?

Comment: yes i tried using some other field also but no luck just to ensure this

Comment: Can we see all your urls.py. I wonder if you are picking up another url path by mistake.

Comment: In your template what do you see if you add something like `<h1>Count of events is {{ event.count }}</h1>` Does it say 0 or give you a positivie integer?

Comment: @MattSeymour u were right. there was a path duplicacy. thanks for your effor

Comment: @AayushGupta those kind of issues are usually easy to debug by tracing code execution (adding a couple `print()` calls in your view or setting a debugger breakpoint).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common issue is that your urls.py might have duplicate entries or a duplicate valid entry. In this case the first path to match will be evaluated and eventually rendered.

Please check your urls.py for any paths which might be called by mistake.